# How do I configure/initialize a custom Elasticsearch Tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch

I am writing a custom Elasticsearch Tokenizer.  The documentation only specifies a constructor for passing a Reader for getting the string to be tokenized and an incrementToken() method for producing the tokens.  I can see no signs of an option to configure the tokenizer.  I see references to Lucene TokenizerFactories that seem to provide a configuration option, but don't see them mentioned in any Elasticsearch context.  My tokenizer is a trivial extension of the base Tokenizer class:

```
public class LCCNTokenizer extends Tokenizer {
    private final CharTermAttribute termAtt = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    public LCCNTokenizer(Reader reader) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How do I configure a custom Elasticsearch Tokenizer?

Comment: Can you show some bits on how you extended the base Tokenizer class?

Comment: Don't hesitate to update your question with that code, it will be more legible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to create a [new ES Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.2/plugin-authors.html). A sample Java plugin is [available here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/plugins/jvm-example).

I would check how a standard analysis plugin is being built, let's take for instance the [Kuromoji analysis plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/plugins/analysis-kuromoji/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/plugin/analysis/kuromoji/AnalysisKuromojiPlugin.java). As you can see, it registers its own tokenizer by registering a [`KuromojiTokenizerFactory`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/plugins/analysis-kuromoji/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/plugin/analysis/kuromoji/AnalysisKuromojiPlugin.java#L52).

So you also need to create a factory for your tokenizer, let's call it `LCCNTokenizerFactory`, which you're going to register in your plugin class as we saw above.

Now this is where the "magic" happens. In your `LCCNTokenizerFactory` class, you'll have a [constructor](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/plugins/analysis-kuromoji/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/analysis/KuromojiTokenizerFactory.java#L45), which looks like this:

```
public LCCNTokenizerFactory(IndexSettings indexSettings, Environment env, String name, Settings settings) {
    param1 = settings.getAsBoolean("param1", true);
    param2 = settings.getAsString("param2", null);
    param3 = settings.getAsDouble("param3", 0.0);
}
```

In this constructor, you can now retrieve any custom settings that you need in order to configure the tokenizer you're about to create.

Finally, you override the `onCreate` method in order to create an instance of your own tokenizer with the custom settings you've parsed in the factory constructor earlier.

```
@Override
public Tokenizer create() {
    return new LCCNTokenizer(param1, param2, param3);
}
```

This is not a complete example, but it should get you going.

Comment: Hey, did this help or do you need more info?

Comment: It was a start and I'm grateful.  I've accepted your answer.  The real problem is that the Elasticsearch extension mechanism is undocumented (well, there is a page, but it proudly proclaims that it is out of date).  People, like you, point at examples from different versions of ES and it looks like the extension mechanism changes every 5 minutes, so none of them are applicable to my situation.  I finally noticed that the download for my version of ES includes the plugins for that version and they were close enough to get me going.  Thanks!